# SSHPass Works in Terminal, but not in Python Script - Permission Denied, Please Try Again

Tags: python, ssh, scp, sshpass

I'm trying to get a .jpg file from my Pi Zero and transmitting it to my Pi 3B using SCP with SSHPass. 
Here is my code:

```
for x in range(0, count):
        client.exec_command('sudo -E python3 startup.py')
        name = "img"+str(x)
        print(name)
        output = subprocess.check_output("pwd", shell=True)
        output = str(output)[2:(len(str(output))-2)]
        os.system("pwd")
        print(output)
        command=("sshpass -p \'raspberry\' scp raspberrypizero.local:img.jpg "+name+".jpg")
        print(command)
        subprocess.Popen('./go.sh')
        print("Running")
```

And the code in **go.sh**:

```
#!/bin/sh
sshpass -p 'raspberry' scp raspberrypizero.local:img.jpg img0.jpg
```

Whenever I run the go.sh command in a terminal, at the same directory, it works perfectly fine and the image is successfully transmitted. 
However, whenever I try to run the command in a python script, I get this output:

```
sshpass -p 'raspberry' scp raspberrypizero.local:img.jpg img1.jpg
Permission denied, please try again.
Running
```

I have tried to use `os.system` as well as `subprocess.call`, however neither of these work.

So, if anyone could let me know or have an idea of why sshpass / scp is working in the terminal, but not when executing it via a python script, that would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: What user are you running the bash script as? You need to change to that user

Comment: @AK47 I used os.getuid() and it showed that in the terminal, the uid was 1000 and in the python script it was 0. So, I used os.setuid() at the top of the main method, and it fixed the issue! Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: No problem ....!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also can use the following command:

```
sudo python3 xxxxx.py
```

and then:

```
command=("sudo sshpass -p \'raspberry\' scp raspberrypizero.local:img.jpg "+name+".jpg")
```